# Django: Can't access data on template through foreign_key

Tags: django

I want to access `transaction_ambassador` in my template. Therefore my approach is going through the order model as I already use it and it's foreign_key. What I did was

```
{{ order.ambassador_transaction }}
```

But all I get is `ambassadors.AmbassadorTransaction.None`. I checked it several times, but it is connected through the `foreign_key`. Anyone knows what I am doing wrong here?

[image]

views.py

```
class OrderListView(ListView):
    allow_empty = False
    template_name = 'orders/order_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Attendee.objects.filter(
            order__order_reference=self.kwargs['order_reference'],
            order__access_key=self.kwargs['access_key'],
        )

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['order'] = Order.objects.get(
            order_reference=self.kwargs['order_reference'],
        )
        return context
```

models.py

```
class AmbassadorTransaction(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(
        Order,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name='ambassador_transaction'
    )
    ambassador = models.ForeignKey(
        AmbassadorProfile,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name='ambassador_profile'
    )

class Order(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(
        Event,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name='orders'
    )
    order_reference = models.CharField(
        max_length=10,
        unique=True,
    )
    total_gross = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=25,
        decimal_places=2
    )
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `ambassador_transaction` foreign key in your `Order` model.

If you want to access all the `AmbassadorTransaction` related to an instance of `Order`, you can iterate over `order.ambassador_transaction_set.all()` in your view or `order.ambassador_transaction.all` in your template.

You can also access the order from the `AmbassadorTransaction` object using `ambassador_transaction.order`

Answer (score 0):

Since your `models.ForeignKey(...)` is in `AmbassadorTransaction` and not in  `Order` then this is a solution:

```
{% for ambassador in order.ambassador_transaction.all %}
  ...
{% endfor %}
```